# Will changing the folder name two directories above a fresh wordpress installation break the site?

Tags: multisite, database, mysql, wp-config, phpmyadmin

I have a client who would like two Wordpress installs on his LAMP stack.

The thing is he forgot to give me the directory names that he wants them on. So as per standard LAMP stack each site will be /var/www. These will be completely blank Wordpress installs, so I'm wondering if I'll be able to name each folder on this directory something like "wordpress1" and "wordpress2" and be able to rename them to something more aesthetically pleasing post install, before the domain and vHost is all setup.

I know that this would definitely mess things up for the virtualhost file but they're not connected to a domain yet and won't be hosted quite yet either, all that can come later.

The part I'm most concerned about is the mySQL database. I took a look at some other Wordpress databases I host and didn't find anything specific to this outside directory but I'm still not confident that it isn't.

Would I be safe to do this assuming the vhost and domain parts are coming later?

Comment: Hi, if you mean you want to install wordpress in a subdirectory with custom name, then no, it doesn't matter. You can install wordpress in any folder in the root.

Answer (score 0):

It might be unsafe in some cases. You should export DATABASE .SQL file and search inside that, all string containing the phrase: `var/www` and `var\www` and `var\\www` and change those entries too. (you can do that in phpmyadmin too)